# GITLAB: WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE

Tags: linux, ssh, gitlab

Система: Ubuntu 23

Возникла необходимость в двух ssh ключах.

1-ый ключ генерирую для school_21, у них свой сервер на базе gitlab.

2-ой ключ генерирую для своего личного gitlab-а.
Сначала я удалил все ключи:

```
$ ssh-add -D
```

Потом провел генерацию двух ключей. Первый сохранил в родной ~/.ssh, второй в папку ~/.ssh/personal_gitlab/

Затем добавляю оба этих ключа с помощью `ssh-add`.
Через `ssh-add -l` они просматриваются.

Оба ключа добавляю на сайте gitlab. (как и сказал ранее, у school_21 свой репозиторий, работающий на gitlab,но они по сути одинаковые)

С первым ключом, который для school_21 все впорядке.
Проекты клонируются, пушатся без проблем.

Со вторым проблема:

```
$ git clone git@gitlab.com:username/repos.git
>
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@         WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
Permissions 0644 for '/home/clipslemon/.ssh/personal_gitlab/id_rsa.pub' are too open.
It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.

git@gitlab.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Так же содержимое `/.ssh/config`:

```
Host gitlab.com
   Hostname gitlab.com
   User ClipsLemon
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/personal_gitlab/id_rsa.pub
   IdentitiesOnly yes
Host 21-school.ru
   Hostname 21-school.ru
   User 'Some Name'
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
   IdentitiesOnly yes
```

Что пробовал:

Менял доступ через `chmod` для ключей. Ставил:

```
chmod u+x
chmod 600
chmod 400
```

Так же ставил тот тип, что указан в ошибке

> Permissions 0644 for ...

Почитал статьи по ssh-agent, ssh-add, искал на форумах ответы. Однако все решения сводятся как правило к файлу config, либо chmod для id_rsa.

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: `IdentityFile` должен содержать путь к закрытому/приватному ключу, без всяких `.pub`

Comment: @andreymal, какая же глупая с моей стороны была ошибка. Потратил зря час своей жизни.
Вам спасибо за комментарий.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка в конфиг файле в строке `IdentityFile ~/.ssh/personal_gitlab/id_rsa.pub`.

Не должно быть `.pub`.